# cuda out of memory problem in gpu in google colab

Tags: embedding, bert-language-model, flair

I am trying to run code to get stacked embedding from flair and bert and I am getting the following error. one of the suggestion was to reduce the batch size, but how to pass the data in batches? here is the code and error.

```
from tqdm import tqdm ## tracks progress of loop ##
import torch
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.embeddings import TransformerDocumentEmbeddings

from flair.embeddings import DocumentPoolEmbeddings
bert_embeddings = TransformerDocumentEmbeddings('bert-base-uncased')

### initialize the document embeddings, mode = mean ###
document_embeddings = DocumentPoolEmbeddings([
                                             flair_forward, 
                                             flair_backward,
                                              bert_embeddings 
                                             ])
# Storing Size of embedding #
z = sentence.embedding.size()[0]
print(z)
### Vectorising text ###
# creating a tensor for storing sentence embeddings
sen = torch.zeros(0,z)
print(sen)

# iterating Sentences #
for tweet in tqdm(txt):   
  sentence = Sentence(tweet)
  document_embeddings.embed(sentence)# *****this line is giving error*****
  # Adding Document embeddings to list #
  if(torch.cuda.is_available()):
    sen = sen.cuda()
  sen = torch.cat((sen, sentence.embedding.view(-1,z)),0)
```

and this the error I am getting.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-1eee00445350> in <module>()
     24 for tweet in tqdm(txt):
     25   sentence = Sentence(tweet)
---> 26   document_embeddings.embed(sentence)
     27   # Adding Document embeddings to list #
     28   if(torch.cuda.is_available()):

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    580         if batch_sizes is None:
    581             result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers,
--> 582                               self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional, self.batch_first)
    583         else:
    584             result = _VF.lstm(input, batch_sizes, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias,

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 7.43 GiB total capacity; 6.54 GiB already allocated; 10.94 MiB free; 6.70 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Comment: What is the dimension of your `sentence` variable?

Comment: the shape of sentence variable [6424,2864]

Comment: So, do you have 6424 examples?

Comment: yes@AshwinGeetD'Sa

Comment: Try passing small number of samples to `document_embeddings`: `document_embeddings.embed(sentence[:32])` (Here, you are passing 32 samples). look for the small number of samples, that can execute that like without any error. You can even go down to size of 1. Here this is called as `batch size`

Answer (score 1):

```
embeddings = FlairEmbeddings('news-forward', chars_per_chunk=128)
```

for example :

```
embedding_types = [
    WordEmbeddings('glove'),
    FlairEmbeddings('news-forward',chars_per_chunk=128),
    FlairEmbeddings('news-backward'),
]
```

Edit your code accordingly new function added by flair to avoid this to see if it works. Google collab is not suitable for large transformers models for tasks such as NER, from my own experience.

> see github documentation for more examples for your specific task!